# Using non-Railsy route to prepopulate a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, url

I have many instances of a Rails model, `Post`. When viewing an individual post, I'd like to create a form to create a child of `Post` called `Comment`. I'd like to prepopulate this form with a hidden tag that contains the `post_id` which is the foreign key in `Comment`.

The Railsy way to do this is to create a fancy-ish route such as:

```
/comments/new/post/:post_id
```

However, this gunks up the routes file and doesn't leave much flexibility. Let's say I want to create a link somewhere else that prepopulates a different attribute of the form...then I'd have to add another route for this.

So I think I'm going to create urls like this on `/posts/show/:id`:

```
/comments/new?comment[post_id]=<%= @post.id %>
```

This way I can add any other attributes as I need. I know the plus side associated with this, now what are the downsides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `new_comment_path :comment => { :post_id => @post.id }` to create such URLs. You could wrap it into a helper if you'd like.

However, there should be no downside with the `/comments/new/post/:post_id` URL style, as you can add further parameters, too:

```
new_post_comment_path @post, :comment => { :additional => "parameters", ... }
```

would result in

```
/posts/:post_id/comments/new?comment[additional]=parameters&...
```

and in your action do:

```
def new
  @post = Post.find params[:post_id]
  @comment = @post.build params[:comment]
end
```

and render your form...